# azure "Cloud Services": what do we do with these relating to our Azure VMs?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to get a handle on the significance of the cloud service (that is created when a new VM is created). I understand that a group of VMs need to belong to the same cloud service in order to participate in Load Balancing. I can't see any other reason to group VMs into a single Cloud Service. On the other hand it seems like overkill to create a cloud service for each VM.

Are there any advantages/reasons to adding a group of VMs to Cloud Service other than Load Balancing?

Thx

Comment: Is it really possible to add Azure VMs to a cloud service? Don't you have to first upload a package and then expect the environment to start the role instances and run the package there?

Comment: Are you talking about Virtual Machines, or web/worker roles?

Comment: @sharptooth yes, in fact this happens automatically creating a cloud service with the same name as the VM

Comment: @DavidMakogon Virtual Machines

Answer (score 2):

A few time ago I asked Mr Haishi Bai from Microsoft about Cloud Services in Virtual Machines.

I'll post what he answered to me:

> "Cloud Service is a container of resources. It can hold Web Roles,
>   Worker Roles as well as Virtual Machines. Cloud Service defines a
>   scope of security, management and communication. Resources within the
>   same Cloud Service can communicate via internal endpoints. Having VMs
>   in Cloud Services allow them to be load-balanced as well. Multiple VMs
>   in a Cloud Service can share the same public endpoint, allowing
>   traffic to be distributed among them."